# Python Tkintet: No entiendo porque el Text() no se muestra

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un editor de código, y quiero que haya un `Text()` (es pequeño, decidí utilizar un `Text` en vez de un `Entry()`) en el que puedas cambiar el nombre del archivo y un `Button()` para confirmar tus cambios. Al confirmar los cambios, te envía un `messagebox.showinfo()` diciéndote que el nombre se cambió con éxito, el problema es que esto no sucede y también debería actualizarse el titulo (`window.title()`) de la ventana con el nuevo nombre. Esta es la función que ejecuta el botón de guardar el nuevo nombre

```py
# Aclaro, esto es lo que importe:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb

# Este es el Text() En el que puedes cambiar el nombre del archivo
name = Text(window, width=20, height=1)
name.insert(END, nombrearch)
name.pack(side=LEFT)
name.place(x=5, y=6)

# Y aca abajo esta la funcion que utiliza el boton (no es necesario que ponga el codigo del boton)
def guardar_nombre():
    nombrearch = name #
    mb.showinfo("Cambio de nombre", "Se ha guardado el nuevo nombre") # Te avisa que se ha cambiado
    window.title((str(nombrearch)," - MinCode")) # Aqui se actualiza el titulo de la ventana
```

Todo debería salir bien, pero este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta acá todo bien, sale el aviso y...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si te fijas en el titulo, aparece ".!text { - MinCode}"

No entiendo porque pasa esto ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

En esta línea de tu código:

```
nombrearch = name #
```

Estás asignando a la variable `nombrearch`, el valor de `name`, pero `name` es el propio objeto widget, no el contenido del mismo.

**Solución:**

Si lo que quieres es asignar a la variable el contenido del cuadro de texto, debes poner esta línea en su lugar:

`nombrearch = name.get('1.0','end')`

Los parámetros pasados son el inicio y el final de las posiciones del texto que contiene el widget (Suponemos que quieres recuperar todo el texto, si no, deberías indicar otras coordenadas).

Mi consejo es que para esta tarea, utilices un widget `Entry` en lugar de un `Text`, que te resultará más fácil de gestionar. En ese caso, para obtener el valor no tienes que indicar ningún parámetro adicional y quedaría así:

```
nombrearch = name.get()
```